# SQL Query (STUFF)

Tags: sql

This is what I did:

```
SELECT 
    [tbl_flw].[question_id], [tbl_flw].[project_id], 
    [tbl_flw].[follow_up_ans], [tbl_flw].[follow_up_ques], 
    [t1].[question] AS current_ques, 
    [t2].[question] AS followUp_ques, 
    displayname = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [tbl_ques].[question] 
                         FROM [tbl_flw] 
                         LEFT JOIN [tbl_ques] ON [tbl_ques].[question_id] = [tbl_flw].[follow_up_ques] 
                         WHERE [tbl_flw].[follow_up_ques] = [tbl_ques].[question_id] 
                         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM 
    [tbl_flw] 
INNER JOIN 
    [tbl_ques] t1 ON t1.question_id = [tbl_flw].[question_id] 
INNER JOIN 
    [tbl_ques] t2 ON t2.question_id = [tbl_flw].[follow_up_ques] 
WHERE  
    [project_id] = 162
```

This is the result

[image: 2]

This is how I want:

But I'm trying to put it like this:

[image: 3]

How to change the SQL query so it will be like result above (displayname column)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't copy your sql code so I'll give you some example.

If you want to concat columns by group you can use GROUP_CONCAT function like this

```
SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(cate_id)
FROM book_mast
GROUP BY pub_id;
```

If you want to use a seperator

```
SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(cate_id SEPERATOR ',')
FROM book_mast
GROUP BY pub_id;
```

And if you want to order the group and use concat unique values

```
SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cate_id ORDER BY cate_id ASC SEPERATOR ',')
FROM book_mast
GROUP BY pub_id;
```

edit : this should work

```
SELECT [tbl_flw].[question_id], [tbl_flw].[project_id], [tbl_flw].[follow_up_ans], 
[tbl_flw].[follow_up_ques], [t1].[question] AS current_ques, [t2].[question] AS followUp_ques, 
displayname = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [tbl_ques].[question] FROM [tbl_flw] 
LEFT JOIN [tbl_ques] ON [tbl_ques].[question_id] = [tbl_flw].[follow_up_ques] 
WHERE[tbl_flw].[follow_up_ques] = [tbl_ques].[question_id] AND [t1].[question] = [tbl_ques].[question] FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM [tbl_flw] 
INNER JOIN [tbl_ques] t1 ON t1.question_id = [tbl_flw].[question_id] 
INNER JOIN [tbl_ques] t2 ON t2.question_id = [tbl_flw].[follow_up_ques] 
WHERE [project_id] = 162
```

Comment: sorry, just edited it with code. no, I'm not trying to use concat actually